# How to make padding of a structure using Perl

Tags: perl, struct

I am creating a structure from the data below which will be in a text file

```
 BO_ 82 Sim_Tracker_Objects3: 8 
  SG_ CAN_Trk_Obj_Sim_Enable : 60|4@1+ (1,0) [0|1] 
  SG_ CAN_Trk_Obj_Curvi_Long_Vel : 32|12@1+ (0.1,-200) [-200|200] 
  SG_ CAN_Trk_Obj_Curvi_Lat_Vel : 48|12@1+ (0.1,-200) [-200|200] 
  SG_ CAN_Trk_Obj_Curvi_Long_Posn : 0|16@1+ (0.01,-200) [-200|200] 
  SG_ CAN_Trk_Obj_Curvi_Lat_Posn : 16|16@1+ (0.01,-200) [-200|200]
```

The Perl script I am using to generate structure is as below
but I want it to be structure padded; how can I do it?

```
open (DBC, "test.txt")|| die "cant open dbc $!";
@test =  <test>;
close (DBC);

open(OUTFILE1,">typedef.h") || die  "cannot open typedef.h\n";
$line_test =$#test;
$delimiter=0;
foreach $line(@test)
{

    if($line =~/^BO_ /)
    { 
    if($delimiter gt 0)
    {
        print OUTFILE1 "}@my_string\n";
    }
    $delimiter=1;
    @dum_struct_name  = split(":",$line);
    if($dum_struct_name[0]=~/BO_ /)
    {
        @dum_struct_var  = split(" ",$line);
        @my_string =  $dum_struct_var[2];
        my $my_struct = chop(@my_string[0]);
        print OUTFILE1 "\n typedef struct\t";
        #print OUTFILE1 "@my_string\n";
        print OUTFILE1 "{\n";
    }              

  }
if($line =~/^ SG_ /)
  {
@dum_var_name  = split(":",$line);
    if($dum_var_name[0]=~/^ SG_ /)
    {

    @dum_struct_var_sub  = split(" ",$line);
    @my_string_sub =  $dum_struct_var_sub[1];
    @dum_padd_var = split("SG_",@dum_var_name[1]);
    print OUTFILE "\n";
    @dum_padd_var1=split("@",@dum_padd_var[0]);
    @padd_size=split(" ",@dum_padd_var1[0]); 
    @size=split('\|',@padd_size[0]);
    @bit_position=split('\|',@padd_size[1]);
    print OUTFILE "bit_size @size[1]\n";
    print OUTFILE "bit_position @size[0]\n";
    print OUTFILE1 "\tcanbittype\t";
    print OUTFILE1 "@my_string_sub[0]:";
    print OUTFILE1 " @size[1];\n";
}
   }   
}   print OUTFILE1 "}";
print OUTFILE1 "@my_string\n";



 close(OUTFILE1);
```

The generated file is something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    canbittype CAN_Trk_Obj_Sim_Enable: 4; 
    canbittype CAN_Trk_Obj_Vcs_Lat_Vel: 12;
    canbittype CAN_Trk_Obj_Vcs_Long_Vel: 12;
    canbittype CAN_Trk_Obj_Vcs_Lat_Posn: 16;
    canbittype CAN_Trk_Obj_Vcs_Long_Posn: 16;
} Sim_Tracker_Objects3;
```

Comment: Please explain properly what it is that you want to do, and show the Perl code you have written so far

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to read from and write to C structures.  If so, look at the pack and unpack functions in Perl.

Comment: "Make structural padding for a structure" is vague. Please explain more specifically what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i need that structure padded how can i do that

Comment: i have many such structures which should be structure padded using perl can u help with that @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by 'structure padded'.  It isn't a term that makes any sense to me.  You've got bitfields all over the place, which are inherently not portable.  However, that's your problem.  What do you want that's different from what you say you want generated?

Comment: for example am using a 8 byte memory to store that data for using that memory space effectively i need them to be arranged in correct order such that the whole data is arranged in that 8byte memory only

Comment: am not sure wether am able to give u correct explanation ? did u get my point here ? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: size specified with that variables is in bits

Comment: The whole business of layout of bitfields is intensely compiler specific.  No-one can help you without knowing what rules your compiler applies.  Those rules are likely to be complex.  They may be different for the 32-bit and 64-bit compilers on the same machine.  They may also be under-documented, even though the standard says almost everything related to bitfields is implementation defined, which means the implementation is supposed to document what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Convert::Binary::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Convert%3a%3aBinary%3a%3aC) or roll out your own [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) pattern.